# ASP.NET treeview performance issue with IE7,8

Tags: asp.net, performance, c#-4.0, treeview

I am using treeview in my asp.net application which have 2000 nodes in it. The treeview takes 40 sec to load on IE7,8 while same page takes 1/10th time on Firefox and chrome. Is there any solution to this problem. Tried searching for this but found only unanswered questions. If this is a limitation of IE 7,8 then what is the reason for it. Is it because of the rendering engine. Is there any solution to the problem ? I mean i tried using the jquery treeview but again it hangs the IE and alert popups up for slow script.

Please help.

Comment: Can you show your treeview control so we can see which properties you have set etc?

Comment: It is a normal asp treeview control but the only thing is that there is a lot of javascript which runs on render. Page takes 4-5 seconds on FF while 40 secs on IE8.

Comment: From a usability perspective, a page containing a treeview with 2000 nodes is next to useless.

Comment: I agree.. but that is the requirement and weired requirements lead into innovations :)

Comment: @IrishChieftain - I disagree.  If the nodes are collapsed, then there's nothing wrong with having a very large number of items, from a usability standpoint (if there's 2000 top-level nodes, then I'd agree with you).  For point-of-reference, open up a Windows Explorer window on your c: drive.  The left-side tree contains far more than 2000 total nodes, but it's still completely usable.

Comment: Windows Explorer is not a website.

Comment: @mikemanne - i accept the answers. But those which doesnt solve the purpose or are not answers, i dont mark them.
@IrishChieftain - i agree with you that a page showing this much data is next to unusable. But the requirement is such and i am looking if there is any solution to this problem

Comment: @Ankit - if you don't post your javascript which you run on page load I don't know that we can really help much more with this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this jQuery plugin? http://www.jstree.com/

It supports AJAX loading, which is great for a 2000 node tree.

Comment: I dont want ajaz tree. What i am looking for is the mechanism with which i can render the whole treeview at one go and WITH PERFORMANCE

Answer (score 1):

There must be something else going on.  I did some performance testing on TreeView and was able to render a complex tree structure containing 5000 nodes in far less time then 40 seconds.  A 2000 node complex tree rendered in about 3 seconds in IE8.  If you can provide some more details about your tree maybe I can provide more assistance.

I've read that the amount of rendered HTML is one of the biggest factors when it comes to rendering time on a big tree.  Even simple things such as reducing the length of a URL string by shortening a page name (if your nodes link directly to pages) or replacing CSS classes with more advanced style sheet usage techniques can make it considerably faster.

Below is my code for generating a random complex tree of `_nodeCount` size:

ASPX Page has a TreeView named tv:

```
<asp:TreeView ID="tv" runat="server"></asp:TreeView>
```

Code Behind looks like the following:

```
private Random _rand = new Random();
private int _nodeCount = 2000;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        //create a big tree
        var itemCount = 0;
        while (itemCount < _nodeCount)
        {
            //create a parent item
            var n = new TreeNode("Node " + itemCount.ToString(), itemCount.ToString());
            itemCount++;

            tv.Nodes.Add(n);

            CreateSubItem(n, ref itemCount);
        }
    }
}

protected void CreateSubItem(TreeNode parent, ref int itemCount)
{
    //chance that we won't create a sub item
    if (_rand.Next(2) == 1 || itemCount > _nodeCount)
    {
        return;
    }

    var n = new TreeNode("Child Node " + itemCount.ToString(), itemCount.ToString());
    itemCount++;

    parent.ChildNodes.Add(n);

    CreateSubItem(n, ref itemCount);
    CreateSubItem(parent, ref itemCount);
}
```

**Update 7/20**
Perhaps you could take the logic in your javascript for setting icons and move it into .NET code, this should greatly reduce the page load time.  This page, http://weblogs.asp.net/dannychen/archive/2006/01/25/436454.aspx, shows how to customize the rendering of a TreeNode; maybe it could be a good starting place for you.

Comment: I have turned off the viewstate to make the page light weight but still it takes 50 secs to load on IE8. The problem is that i have to change the icon of the nodes and this is possible only through javascript after page render. The render thus takes time as it iterates on the nodes and according to the logic, it changes the icon of the treeview nodes. there is no css involved, just js.

Comment: It seems the real issue is that you need to improve the performance of your Javascript or find another way to set the icons such that you can improve performance.  Can you post the javascript code so that I can try and help?

Comment: @Ankit - I've updated my answer to include a link which talks about custom TreeNode rendering.  Maybe you can convert your javascript to .Net code and improve your performance that way.

Comment: The link you provided shows how to update the text. My requirement is to update the icon (plus and minus) with some custom image.

Comment: @Ankit - The link was just a starting point.  Given the examples available it shouldn't take much to figure out how to do more then just custom text rendering.

Answer (score 1):

When you open the rendered html generated from the tree view, you will find that the control generate a hell of html table, tr and td which I think is taking a very long time to be rendered on IE so I suggest that you create a new custom web control that inhertis from the treeview control and update the "Render Method" to write Div's instead of HTML and this will require a professional developer and HTML designer to do this.

I think you can after that share this new control with the community and we can enhance on it with you to get rid of this dummy asp.net gridview.

Comment: Per my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435445/asp-net-treeview-performance-issue-with-ie7-8/6734147#6734147, the real issue is his custom javascript which he is using for setting icons.  My answer demonstrates generating TreeViews that are much larger and still take only a few seconds to render in IE.

Answer (score 0):

It is always good to use AJAX in your application and load the treeview dynamically via AJAX. Here is a link...

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/selfloadelement.aspx

Comment: Tried it but the script becomes unresponsive. Do you have any code to support?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the attribute HoverNodeStyle-CssClass="nh" makes the rendering of the TreeView slow in IE9. I removed the attribute and the performance restored.