# IE8 hangs when loading a page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET treeview performance issue with IE7,8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435445/asp-net-treeview-performance-issue-with-ie7-8)

I have a page with a treeview with 2000 nodes in it. When opening that page, the IE8 hangs. Other browsers(Chrome, FF) works fine. The browser hangs (Not Responding) and then reopens and then the page is loaded. Any idea

Update 1: When i used telerik treeview control and render the same number of nodes, it didnt hang but it hangs when using asp.net treeview. So definitely not a problem of huge data.

Comment: 2000 nodes are too much to render.. poor browsers just can't handle it. Use pagination, and show only 100 nodes on each page. Anyway -1 for asking same question again.

Comment: Some sample code showing the tree view and some dummy data would be a start. Anything that allows us to replicate the problem.

Comment: Shadow Wizard: The question in that post was not comparision between telerik and asp.net. I found out answer to how can i resolve the problem. Now i want to understand why was that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does it also hang in Safari?
Cause, i know if you use more than 200 different iframes in Safari it hangs.

Perhaps it is cause of the large amount?

Comment: Please check update.. 
 When i used telerik treeview control and render the same number of nodes, it didnt hang but it hangs when using asp.net treeview. So definitely not a problem of huge data.

Answer (score 0):

There are nesting limits in IE. [This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956615) is what is found related to IE 7.

Comment: When i used telerik treeview control and render the same number of nodes, it didnt hang but it hangs when using asp.net treeview. So definitely not a problem of huge data.

Comment: Just check the html output of both the instances and see if telerik has done it in a different way than the asp.net tree view.

Comment: It renders the treeview in div, spans, ul, li. While asp does it in table ,tr, td

Comment: then that is the problem. you can probably try to do a custom tree view implementation using div/spans/ul/li if it is not an option to use telerik one. ie has knows issues with nested tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lazy-loading for your treeview.

Comment: I want to render the whole tree at once. No lazy loading