# big table makes internet explorer 8 freeze

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer-8

I have a simple ASP.NET MVC3 index page which holds more than 11k items. I have buttons for operation links as an extra. The code is like follows:

```
<table class="list">
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>
        Name
    </th>
    <th>
        Code
    </th>
    <th>
        Explanation
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", new { id = item.ID })" class="noUL">
            <img class="opr" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/edit.png")" alt="Edit" title="Edit" />
        </a>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Details", new { id = item.ID })" class="noUL">
            <img class="opr" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/info.png")" alt="Details" title="Details"/>
        </a>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", new { id = item.ID })" class="noUL">
            <img class="opr" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/delete.png")" alt="Delete" title="Delete"/>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td width="600px">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Code)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Explanation)
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

There's no problem opening it with any other browsers inluding Chrome and Firefox, but in IE8 first it tries running, then locks permanently. I don't expect a good performance from IE, but how can I make it work? Small tips for just saving the day are greatly appreciated. I tried to give static width to a varying sized column, for example.

**UPDATE:** I deleted the image links' column and it worked; even faster with tables, rather than div-ul-li setup I tried before.

Comment: Ouch -- if I try to approximate the payload on this (trying to go conservative/low here), using your markup with the whitespace etc removed (but lacking actually data values) I get 700bytes * 11K rows == 7.7MB  Wow...  How long does it take to transfer and render in Chrome?

Comment: my bad. near 10 seconds.

Comment: Total long-shot: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923063/ie8-hangs-when-loading-a-page -- in particular the last conversation about IE7/8 and many-rowed in TABLES vs. DIV, SPANS, UL etc. for same purpose.  It seems like you could give it a try fairly quick based on your markup.

Comment: Tried div-ul-li setup instead of table-tr-td, but no luck. That was a good idea by the way, thanks.

Comment: Well at least you know that IE sucks consistently!

Comment: Please see my update. I will try adding images with javascript after table loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you if you have bulk data, override the paging on the table. Send your data to table **part by part** with `JSON`. In every *next* or *prev* buttons clicking send new list to table.

Comment: Iyi kodlamalar, Ismet bey